# Python: how to install a pass-through copy/deepcopy hook

Tags: python

I have a library which stores additional data for foreign user objects in a WeakKeyDictionary:

```
extra_stuff = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
def get_extra_stuff_for_obj(o):
    return extra_stuff[o]
```

When user object is copied, I want the copy to have the same extra stuff. However, I have limited control over the user object. I would like to define a class decorator for user object classes which will be used in this manner:

```
def has_extra_stuff(klass):
    def copy_with_hook(self):
        new = magic_goes_here(self)
        extra_stuff[new] = extra_stuff[self]
    klass.__copy__ = copy_with_hook
    return klass
```

This is easy if klass already defines `__copy__`, because I can close `copy_with_hook` over the original and call it. However, typically it's not defined. What to call here? This obviously can't be `copy.copy`, because that would result in infinite recursion.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253439/python-copy-how-to-inherit-the-default-copying-behaviour) which appears to ask the exact same question, but afaict the answer is wrong because this results in a deepcopy, not a copy. I would also be unable to do this, as I need to install hooks for both deepcopy and copy. (Incidentally, I would have continued the discussion in that question, but having no reputation I am not able to do this.)

I looked at what the copy module does, which is a bunch of voodoo involving `__reduce_ex()`. I can obviously cut/paste this into my code, or call its private methods directly, but I would consider this an absolute last resort. This seems like such a simple thing, I'm convinced I'm missing a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you need to (A) copy and preserve the original `__copy__` if present (and delegate to it), otherwise (B) trick `copy.copy` into **not** using your newly-added `__copy__` (and delegate to `copy,copy`).

So, for example...:

```
import copy
import threading

copylock = threading.RLock()

def has_extra_stuff(klass):

    def simple_copy_with_hook(self):
        with copylock:
            new = original_copy(self)
            extra_stuff[new] = extra_stuff[self]

    def tricky_case(self):
        with copylock:
            try:
                klass.__copy__ = None
                new = copy.copy(self)
            finally:
                klass.__copy__ = tricky_case
            extra_stuff[new] = extra_stuff[self]

    original_copy = getattr(klass, '__copy__', None)
    if original_copy is None:
        klass.__copy__ = tricky_case
    else:
        klass.__copy__ = simple_copy_with_hook
    return klass
```

Not the most elegant code ever written, but at least it just plays around with `klass`, without monkey-patching nor copy-and-pasting `copy.py` itself:-)

Added: since the OP mentioned in a comment he can't use this solution because the app is multi-threaded, added appropriate locking to make it actually usable.  Using a single global re-entrant lock to ensure against deadlocks due to out-of-order acquires of multiple locks among multiple threads, and perhaps over-locked "just in case" although I suspect the simple case and the dict assignent in the tricky case probably don't need the lock... but, when threading threatens, better safe than sorry:-)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said in the question: I thought of this, too. Unfortunately the application is multithreaded, so I wouldn't be able to use a solution like this.

Comment: @MatthewBooth, **would** have been nice to mention such a crucial constraint **in your question**, you know?!  Anyway, nothing a global `RLock` around copying couldn't solve.

Comment: Messing with global state is a minefield. This application happens to use threads, but even if it didn't I try to avoid messing with global state. Also, whenever I find myself needing locking for a seemingly trivial problem like this, I try to look long and hard elsewhere first. There's no fundamental reason why threads should be required to serialise here, excepting any serialisation requirements of the registry itself.

The above contains a race:

A: copy.copy(o)
A: o.__copy__ exists
A: lock copylock
A: klass.__copy__ = None
B: copy.copy(o)
B: o.__copy__ is None

Comment: Eurgh, formatting, commit editing restrictions, everything...

2 simultaneous copies of the same object: the hook is only called for one of them. Problem is that by disabling the copy hook you also disable the locking. i.e. You can't implement locking here.

I think the solution below is good.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing I've come up with the following:

```
import copy_reg, copy

# Library
def hook(new):
    print "new object: %s" % new

def pickle_hooked(o):
    pickle = o.__reduce_ex__(2)
    creator = pickle[0]

    def creator_hook(*args, **kwargs):
        new = creator(*args, **kwargs)
        hook(new)
        return new

    return (creator_hook,) + pickle[1:]

def with_copy_hook(klass):
    copy_reg.pickle(klass, pickle_hooked)
    return klass

# Application
@with_copy_hook
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

This registers a pass-through copy hook which also has the advantage of working for both copy and deepcopy. The only detail of the return value of **reduce_ex** it needs to concern itself with is that the first element in the tuple is a creator function. All other details are handed off to existing library code. It is not perfect, because I still don't see a way of detecting if the target class has already registered a pickler.